# Button moved down when I put a long text on it

Tags: android, button

I could explain it but I think an image explains my issue better than words could ever do:

[image: example]

And here's my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    layout="@layout/action_bar" />


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:padding="8dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="150dip"
                android:layout_height="150dip"
                android:text="This is a short text" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="150dip"
                android:layout_height="150dip"
                android:text="This is a long text to show how the button is moved when it has a long text on it" />
        </TableRow>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="150dip"
                android:layout_height="150dip"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="150dip"
                android:layout_height="150dip"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `padding` for the buttons? Try it with 0dp.

Comment: What about getting rid of the `TableRow` around those two top buttons?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same issue. The reason for that is, that the default value of [`baselineAligned`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:baselineAligned) is `true`, so the button is moved down to have the text on the same base line. Setting the value on the LinearLayout to `false` sloves the problem.

```
android:baselineAligned="false"
```

Comment: @santirivera92 I know this question is quiet old, but I wanted to add the real reason for that :-)

Answer (score 3):

What is your ideal situation to happen if the text is too long?

Try adding:

```
android:maxLines:"1"
```

To the buttons.

**EDIT:** I don't know exactly what was causing the issue that you saw, but here is a simpler way to build your layout that seems to fix the problem you were having when run on my device.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >




<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:padding="8dip" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="150dip"
                android:layout_height="150dip"
                android:text="This is a short text" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="150dip"
                android:layout_height="150dip"
                android:text="This is a long text to show how the button is moved when it has a long text on it" 
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"/>




            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="150dip"
                android:layout_height="150dip"
                android:text="Button" 
                android:layout_below="@id/button1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="150dip"
                android:layout_height="150dip"
                android:text="Button" 
                android:layout_below="@id/button1"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I did that and it won't show the full text. Also the button will still be moved down. I just want the two buttons to be aligned no matter what.

Comment: but then what should happen to the text? you can't show all of the text and keep the buttons aligned...

Comment: The text actually fits in a 150x150dip button

Comment: @Tim : "you can't show all of the text and keep the buttons aligned." Why not? If you look at the button at the top-left (which is the same size as the one that moves). The text could easily fit.

Comment: What I meant was that at some point the String size will simply be too big to fit the view (though I agree the one in your example does look like it should fit, at least on the device size that it was screen shotted with). I don't know why it pushed it down like that though.

Comment: whatever the issue, I found a way that seems to have the effect you want, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include 
android:id="@+id/include1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_weight="1" 
layout="@layout/action_bar" /> 

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:padding="8dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >

            <RelativeLayout >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="150dip"
                    android:layout_height="150dip"
                    android:text="This is a short text" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="150dip"
                    android:layout_height="150dip"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
                    android:text="This is a long text to show how the button is moved when it has a long text on it" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="150dip"
                android:layout_height="150dip"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="150dip"
                android:layout_height="150dip"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

add the `</LinearLayout>` last line. it isn't showing in the code.
it must work...